# Addition of On-Demand Resources from terminal

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, on-demand-resources, build-pipeline

I am currently able to use On-Demand Resources in my iOS App but I have to perform a series of manual steps:

- Add ODR resources manually in XCode
- Manually tag them in XCode
- Archive the App in order to generate the bundles that will be submitted to Apple and temporarily push them on a webserver that we use to test ODR on non-prod Apps.

Is there some command-line utility that I can use for this?

Is any automation possible for any of those steps? Is there some command-line utility that I can use for this?

In my case I'm using Cordova so this (still) open PR is all I found so far: https://github.com/apache/cordova-node-xcode/pull/87

Comment: I've used https://github.com/CocoaPods/Xcodeproj for automating the adding and tagging of resources.

Comment: Have you considered using TestFlight? Apple will host the assets like they would on the App Store.

Comment: @JamesP that could be an option, thanks. How do I upload the ODR into TF though? I currently promote them into TF from AppCenter (ex HockeyApp).

Comment: Looks like it can be solved as archive_options with FastLane

Answer (score 0):

Solution I went with:

- Forked cordova plugin https://github.com/apache/cordova-node-xcode/pull/87 to add ODR and tag them in the build pipeline
- A before_build Cordova hook to simply add the value of the external URL for ODR in the App.xcodeproj/project.pbxproj file (like XCode does)
- Fastlane and *archive_options* to set the ODR external URL during the archiving step
- Github API to push the ODR into the remote repo that is used by the (non-prod) Apps to fetch the ODR